# ASN1 Object's schema was not verified against input data for CERT

Tags: javascript, asn.1

Hi I've adapted the HTML certificate parser code to use nodejs from here:

https://github.com/GlobalSign/PKI.js/blob/master/examples/certificate-decode-example.html

However, I keep getting `Error: Object's schema was not verified against input data for CERT`

Obviously, theres a schema verification issue thats seems to be specific to node JS.

Am I missing something here ?

var merge = require("node.extend");

```
 var common = require("asn1js/org/pkijs/common");
 var _asn1js = require("asn1js");
 var _pkijs = require("pkijs");
 var _x509schema = require("pkijs/org/pkijs/x509_schema");

 // #region Merging function/object declarations for ASN1js and PKIjs
 var asn1js = merge(true, _asn1js, common);

 var x509schema = merge(true, _x509schema, asn1js);

 var pkijs_1 = merge(true, _pkijs, asn1js);
 var pkijs = merge(true, pkijs_1, x509schema);


 certb = `
 MIIDdTCCAl2gAwIBAgILBAAAAAABFUtaw5QwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEFBQAwVzELMAkG
 A1UEBhMCQkUxGTAXBgNVBAoTEEdsb2JhbFNpZ24gbnYtc2ExEDAOBgNVBAsTB1Jv
 b3QgQ0ExGzAZBgNVBAMTEkdsb2JhbFNpZ24gUm9vdCBDQTAeFw05ODA5MDExMjAw
 MDBaFw0yODAxMjgxMjAwMDBaMFcxCzAJBgNVBAYTAkJFMRkwFwYDVQQKExBHbG9i
 YWxTaWduIG52LXNhMRAwDgYDVQQLEwdSb290IENBMRswGQYDVQQDExJHbG9iYWxT
 aWduIFJvb3QgQ0EwggEiMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4IBDwAwggEKAoIBAQDaDuaZ
 jc6j40+Kfvvxi4Mla+pIH/EqsLmVEQS98GPR4mdmzxzdzxtIK+6NiY6arymAZavp
 xy0Sy6scTHAHoT0KMM0VjU/43dSMUBUc71DuxC73/OlS8pF94G3VNTCOXkNz8kHp
 1Wrjsok6Vjk4bwY8iGlbKk3Fp1S4bInMm/k8yuX9ifUSPJJ4ltbcdG6TRGHRjcdG
 snUOhugZitVtbNV4FpWi6cgKOOvyJBNPc1STE4U6G7weNLWLBYy5d4ux2x8gkasJ
 U26Qzns3dLlwR5EiUWMWea6xrkEmCMgZK9FGqkjWZCrXgzT/LCrBbBlDSgeF59N8
 9iFo7+ryUp9/k5DPAgMBAAGjQjBAMA4GA1UdDwEB/wQEAwIBBjAPBgNVHRMBAf8E
 BTADAQH/MB0GA1UdDgQWBBRge2YaRQ2XyolQL30EzTSo//z9SzANBgkqhkiG9w0B
 AQUFAAOCAQEA1nPnfE920I2/7LqivjTFKDK1fPxsnCwrvQmeU79rXqoRSLblCKOz
 yj1hTdNGCbM+w6DjY1Ub8rrvrTnhQ7k4o+YviiY776BQVvnGCv04zcQLcFGUl5gE
 38NflNUVyRRBnMRddWQVDf9VMOyGj/8N7yy5Y0b2qvzfvGn9LhJIZJrglfCm7ymP
 AbEVtQwdpf5pLGkkeB6zpxxxYu7KyJesF12KwvhHhm4qxFYxldBniYUr+WymXUad
 DKqC5JlR3XC321Y9YeRq4VzW9v493kHMB65jUr9TU/Qr6cf9tveCX4XSQRjbgbME
 HMUfpIBvFSDJ3gyICh3WZlXi/EjJKSZp4A==
 `;

 var asn1 = pkijs.org.pkijs.fromBER(certb);
 var cert_simpl = new pkijs.org.pkijs.simpl.CERT({ schema: asn1.result });
```